# In $\mathcal{T}=\{\{0,1\}, \emptyset\}$, what are limit points of $1$ and $0$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose I have the topology on $X=\{0,1\}$ given by $\mathcal{T}=\{X, \emptyset\}$.

I know that the sets $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are neither open nor closed, since neither they nor their complements are open sets in the topology.

Define the set of **adherence points** of a set $A \subset X$ to be the set $\overline{A}=\{x \in X \vert \forall \, \text{neighborhoods}\, U(x), \, U(x)\cap A \neq \emptyset\}$. Then, $\overline{\{0\}} = \{0,1\}$, since every neighborhood of $0$ contains $0$ and every neighborhood of $1$ contains $0$. Likewise, $\overline{\{1\}} = \{0,1\}$, since every neighborhood of $0$ contains $1$ and every neighborhood of $1$ contains $1$. Is this correct reasoning on my part?

Moreover, define the set of **limit points** of a set $A \subset X$ to be the set $A^{\prime}=\{x\in X \vert \forall \, \text{neighborhoods}\, U(x): U(x)\cap (A-\{x\})\neq \emptyset\}$. I am trying to figure out what $A^{\prime}$ is for $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$, but I am having some difficulty. I'd think it would be $\emptyset$ for each, because $\{0,1\}$ does not contain any points in, say $\{0\}$ that are distinct from $0$. Am I correct in this reasoning? And if not, could someone please explain to me why?  I'm very confused.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are right for the set of adherence points, however, you could be more precise there. You reason that every neighbourhood of $1$ contains $0$, but writing it down this way does not make perfectly clear, if you understood what is going on here. In fact, in this example, you can write down the neighbourhoods of $1$ explicitly. Concerning the set of limit points, note that you have $A - \{x\} = A$ if $x$ is not an element of $A$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch for the limit points then, what do you mean? I'm even more confused now.

Comment: Consider $A=\{0\}$. Consider $0\in X$. The only open set that contains $0$ is $X$. Observe that $X\smallsetminus \{0\}=\{1\}$, which implies that $$(X\smallsetminus \{0\})\cap A=\emptyset.$$ So, $0\notin A'$. Consider $1\in X$. Here, $X\smallsetminus \{1\}=\{0\}$, and so $$(X\smallsetminus \{1\})\cap A=\{0\}\neq\emptyset .$$ This means that $1\in A'$. Hence, $A'=\{1\}$. Similarly,  if $A=\{1\}$, then $A'=\{0\}$.

Comment: By the way, one can write $A'$ as $$A^{\prime}=\{x\in X \vert \forall \, \text{neighborhoods}\, U(x): (U(x)\smallsetminus\{x\})\cap A\neq \emptyset\}$$

Comment: I was under the assumption that you considered the equation $U(x) \cap (A - \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$ only for $x \in A$, say for $A = \{0\}$, and found that $x = 0$ does not solve it. However for $x = 1$, you have $X \cap (\{0\} - \{1 \} ) = \{0\} \neq \emptyset $ which shows $1 \in \{0\}'$ as ΘΣΦGenSan already showed.